# Migrate Spring Boot project from Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2, aws-codestar

I have a Spring Boot project that is running on an EC2 instance via Elastic Beanstalk. This project was created by AWS CodeStar and they also provided an out-of-the-box project template. You can see the template here: https://github.com/JanHorcicka/AWS-Codestar-Spring-Webapp-EBS-Template

The problem is that this project is automatically deployed to an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 1. To project template is built to work on AL1. Unfortunately, some tools I want to install (Certbot) require Amazon Linux 2. There are ways to switch from AL1 to AL2. For example here: [Create Amazon Linux 2 instance via CodeStar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731028/create-amazon-linux-2-instance-via-codestar/66731777)
The problem is that after I switch to AL2, the provided project template doesn't work.

I know there are some differences for Elastic Beanstalk for different version of AL. For example I read somewhere, that the AL2 is not using .ebextensions folder anymore. But I cannot find the full list of changes.

How do I have to modify the template to make it work also on AL2 instance?